# Index IValueConverter Optimisation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've created an `IValueConverter` in order to Bind to the index value of a Collection.

However it seems to be rather slow/infefficient and I wonder if there is a better/different way to do this.

```
public class IndexValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            CollectionView collectionView = (CollectionView) parameter;
            IList collection = (IList) collectionView.ItemsSource;
        
            int convertedValue = collection.IndexOf(value) + 1;
            return convertedValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            return -1;
        }
    }
        
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<CollectionView     
    x:Name="JobPins"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ACollectionView}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="ADataModel">
            <Label
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                Style="{StaticResource ListLabels}"
                Text="{Binding ., 
                Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter},
                ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=JobPins}}" 
                TextColor="WhiteSmoke" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to optimize that is store indexes directly in the source data. So, the `int` public Property in the `ADataModel`. It's rather faster to refill indexes there with O(n) complexity than with O(n<sup>2</sup>) using Converter.

The code can be a bit optimized: it's better to use bindings to pass the data to Converter. But it's not possible to pass a data to `ConverterParameter` using `Binding`. The `MultiBinding`+`IMultiValueConverter` is the solution.

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ACollectionView}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type ADataModel}">
            <Label BackgroundColor="Black" Style="{StaticResource ListLabels}" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" >
                <Label.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="."/>
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=CollectionView}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Text>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Alternative `Binding` to the Colletion as an option.

```xml
<Binding Path="DataContext.ACollectionView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=CollectionView}"/>
```

Avoid giving names to controls where possible, it would give more flexibility for the future UI improvements.

```cs
public class IndexValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[1] is IList list ? list.IndexOf(values[0]) + 1 : -1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Converting index of the List back is not supported");
    }
}
```

Avoid throwing Exception in converters if you don't want to crash the app. Don't build the app's logic on Exceptions in general.

Comment: Sadly there's a bug with the ConverterParameter in IValueConverter in Xamarin Forms. 

Where you can't bind to anything in ConverterParameter (it becomes null or something weird) 

A workaround for this is either hardcode the value in the XAML or x:reference it. 
The converterParemeter syntax is also slightly wrong, but nothing major. 

ConverterParameter={Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}},Path=ItemsSource}}"

Just writing it down in case anyone that comes across post needs it. Additionally the Convert Method only returns -1 now.

Comment: @J.Dhaik correct, but it isn't a bug but my mistake. I'll fix it later. In short `IMultivalueConverter`+`<MultiBinding>...</MultiBinding>` is needed.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks so much for assisting. Cause I can see your version of doing it is far better.

Comment: @J.Dhaik updated the answer

Comment: Had to modify the MultiBinding slightly, but this works great

 <Label.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="." />
                                            <Binding Path="ItemsSource"
                                                     Source="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}}" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Label.Text>

Comment: It is way way faster than the original solution too, so mission accomplished.

Comment: @J.Dhaik `Converter="{StaticResource IndexConverter}"` - yes, fixed in the answer.